# Is this log form simple enough?

Tags: logarithms

$$\frac{3}{\ln{2}-12}$$
Is this form simplified enough?

There is a number '$12$' below the fraction line, do i need to transform the $\log$ more to make it simpler?

I wrote that in a college math exam

Comment: Simple enough for what?

Comment: Yeah,it seems like we can't make it simplier

Comment: Whether it is simplified enough depends on what you are doing.  If this is a homework answer, then it will depend on what your teacher expects, and what convensions have been set in class.  If this is a part of your own research, then it depends on what additional manipulations you might need to make.  It might be less ambiguous to ask if a simpler form can be found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only complaint I can see is that it obscures the fact that it is negative, so one might prefer $\frac {-3}{12-\ln 2}$ but otherwise I don't see a simpler form.  I guess you could go to $$\frac 3{\ln \frac 2{e^{12}}}=
\frac 1{\ln \sqrt [3]{\frac 2{e^{12}}}}=\frac 1{\ln \frac{\sqrt [3] 2}{e^4}}$$ but I don't think this is progress.